# Suggest dynamic help text for new answerers

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answers

This was [just posted on Meta.SO by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86576/suggest-dynamic-help-text-for-new-answerers):

---

We now have dynamic answer help that pops up for new users (< 100 rep) when they focus the answer box.

[image: Screenshot of "Your answer" help text]

> Thanks for contributing an answer to $SiteName!
>
> This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so please make sure you *answer the question*.
>
> Provide details and share your research. Avoid statements based solely on opinion; only make statements you can back up with an appropriate reference, or personal experiences.

It's kind of related to [this post by Robert](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/940/changing-the-how-to-ask-panel-to-head-off-recipe-questions/942#942) ... but I feel we have plenty of help for question askers already, whereas for **people answering questions** we were telling them *nothing*. This seemed really, really dumb to me when I thought of it 2 days ago. Why weren't we helping random internet users who began to type in the "Your Answer" box? I wish I could go back in time and implement this a year ago.

Anyway, now that we have dynamic answer help for new users -- do you have any suggestions on copyedits? Remember we want just the *absolute minimum you can expect a person to read* so no giant list of do's and don'ts -- just the bare essentials that **new users typing in an answer for the first time should know**.

And yes this can be customized per Q&A site.

---

Please post your suggestions for this help text for our site as answers to this question. We'll then ask Jeff to implement a new help text tailored to the need of our site.

Comment: I'd like to think, just a little, that [we helped push this into existence](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/384/improve-the-answer-box-by-explaining-what-an-answer-is)!

Comment: @Renesis: I was trying to find the question to make it status complete!

Answer (score 5):

Just removing the "or personal experience" part seems enough:

> Thanks for contributing an answer to Skeptics - Stack Exchange!
>
> This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so please make sure you answer the question.
>
> Provide details and share your research. Avoid statements based solely on opinion; only make statements you can back up [with an appropriate reference](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/must-all-claims-be-referenced).

Comment: I added a link to the meta post. Figured it can't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

ok I changed it to

> Thanks for contributing an answer to Skeptics - Stack Exchange!
>
> This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so please make sure you *answer the question*.
>
> Provide details and share your research. Avoid statements based solely on opinion or personal experience; **only make statements you can back up with an appropriate reference**.