# Disclaimer about how references are required @ answer form

Tags: discussion

I propose we should have a disclaimer before the Answer form about how references are must. Since it's official policy of this site anyway.

At the moment we use a bot<sup>[citation needed]</sup> "Sklivvz" to write it in comments of every unsourced answer, but it's kinda waste of time I believe.

Is it technically possible to make such disclaimer for skeptics.SE only, i.e. not disturbing other SE sites?

Comment: +1 for bot[citation needed] "Sklivvz" - and for the idea.

Comment: I use: http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/pro-forma-comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[We already have the following text displayed to new users answering a question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/488/suggest-dynamic-help-text-for-new-answerers):

> Thanks for contributing an answer to Skeptics - Stack Exchange!
>
> This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so please make sure you *answer the question*.
>
> Provide details and share your research. Avoid statements based solely on opinion or personal experience; **only make statements you can back up with an appropriate reference**.

Comment: Sorry I missed it ;) That seems very nice.

Comment: could the wording be tweaked a bit to clarify that "can back up with reference" actually means "MUST proide references. [link] to META discussion on what acceptable references are". Please note that this is a material distinction - I was downvoted by Sklivvz for failing to provide the links to Facebook API, whose existence is an obvious and uniquitous fact. So, I COULD back up the statements (and did immediately upon Sklivvz indicating the need), but was initially downvoted for not providing them upfront, although **I have not violated the rule you quoted**.

Comment: @DVK You can propose a different version of that disclaimer in the meta question I linked. Then you just have to convince Jeff to change it.

Comment: should I first propose the change as a Q on meta?

Comment: @DVK Just reuse the old question for now, if your proposed change meets with approval, we can then try to get Jeffs attention.